# Type punning in C++ via extern "C" function using union

Tags: c++, type-punning

The ubiquitous problem of converting contiguous bytes into other typed objects can be solved in C using unions. This is not possible in C++ due the active-member definition.

Therefore, in the following snippet the actual "punning" is done by a C-function. I wonder if this is correct? This for sure depends on the meaning of the "extern" keyword.

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstddef>
#include <string.h>

namespace Util {
    namespace detail {
        union Punn {
            std::byte small[sizeof(uint32_t)];
            uint32_t  big;
        };
    }
    extern "C" {
    inline uint32_t read(const Util::detail::Punn* u) {
        return u->big;
    }
    }
}

int main() {
    Util::detail::Punn a;
    a.small[0] = std::byte{1};
    a.small[1] = std::byte{2};
    a.small[2] = std::byte{3};
    a.small[3] = std::byte{4};

    auto x = Util::read(&a);

    return x;
}
```

I know that the two real save solutions the this problem are shifts or memcpy(). So, please only argue about the above code using extern "C" function. (Aside: the generated assembler code is correct on g++, but that doesn't mean, that it is strictly conforming.)

Comment: This is not really a "C function", it just has C linkage (i.e. there's no name-mangling or whatever).

Comment: ...though if you move it to a TU you compile with a C compiler, it may pun. Just not any C++ types.

Comment: `extern “C”` does not mean “compile this code as C”. It means “compile this code so that it can be linked with C code”. It’s still C++.

Comment: If I move the function ' read()' to another TU, it won't be inlined. And I don't see a way to achieve that.